# How can I dark-theme in bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs2, datepicker

Now I am using [https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

I searched options and read docs carefully, I can't find to use dark-them.

I am using Vue.

please let me know if sb knows this and has experience used this.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap datetimepicker does not have dark theme out of the box.

If you are using Vue, I would suggest to use Vue orientated datetimepicker that *can* support dark theme.

A few examples are:

https://mariomka.github.io/vue-datetime/ - supports theming and styling on your own
- https://vcalendar.io/colors-dark-mode.html - supports theming and has got dark mode

If not, I am sure you can style the bootstrap-datetimepicker to match any dark theme you would like.

Comment: I'd like to show calendar and timepicker with inline. i searched those links, but i couldn't find it.

Comment: and also, in this https://vcalendar.io/colors-dark-mode.html, I can't find to set timepicker.